# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed' . Renaming image django models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I am downloading images by links using `requests` and saving them to the model

```
f = open('00000001.jpg','wb')
f.write(requests.get('http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg').content)
event.image = f
f.close()
```

Error on event.save() happens:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock2/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock2/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 762, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock2/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in _save_table
    for f in non_pks]
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock2/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 312, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Googled for a while, and understood that something is just likely wrong with the method of naming images with id instead, but can't really understand what's exactly wrong and why

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return 'event_img/{0}'.format(instance.event.id)

class Event(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [`FieldFile.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) but basically you can do the following:

```
from django.core.files import File
...
event.image.save(f.name, File(f))
```